# Runtime Vue error Laravel 8 and Jetstream VUE_PROD_DEVTOOLS not defined

Tags: laravel, vue.js, npm

I am getting this error:

> app.js?id=37395f80948d4d99f537:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: VUE_PROD_DEVTOOLS is not defined at Module.5166 (app.js?id=37395f80948d4d99f537:2)

When I run a new Laravel 8 install with Jetstream, having run `npm run prod`. It works fine with `npm run dev`. Home page will not render at all with the prod version. I have the Vue dev tools extension in Chrome installed, with the allow access to file URLs option turned on.

Comment: I have the same problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into this same error, and was able to resolve it by ensuring 'webpack.config.js' has the following:

`const webpack = require('webpack')`

`module.exports = {`
   `plugins: [`
       `new webpack.DefinePlugin({`
           `__VUE_PROD_DEVTOOLS__: 'false'`
       `})`
   `],`
`};`

This is in addition to whatever else you have in your webpack.config.js file.
Also note that `npm run prod` may be different than `npm run production`
I found this solution at https://github.com/visualfanatic/vue-svg-loader/issues/136

Answer (score 1):

Both George Brotherston and WeAreModus from Laracasts are right, fbloggs.

When using Vue 3.0.0-rc.3 you need to set __VUE_PROD_DEVTOOLS__ explicitly.

This bug fixed in v3.0.7.

[See Github issue resolution](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-next/pull/2906)

---

[See docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue/v/3.0.5)

Bundler Build Feature Flags
Starting with 3.0.0-rc.3, esm-bundler builds now exposes global feature flags that can be overwritten at compile time:

**VUE_OPTIONS_API** (enable/disable Options API support, default: true)

**VUE_PROD_DEVTOOLS** (enable/disable devtools support in production, default: false)
The build will work without configuring these flags, however it is strongly recommended to properly configure them in order to get proper tree-shaking in the final bundle. To configure these flags:

webpack: use DefinePlugin

Rollup: use @rollup/plugin-replace

Vite: configured by default, but can be overwritten using the define option

Note: the replacement value must be boolean literals and cannot be strings, otherwise the bundler/minifier will not be able to properly evaluate the conditions.

Comment: Thanks. I accepted the other answer, although I appreciate you showing me this in the docs. I do still think this is a bug - the docs you quote clearly state 'the build will work without configuring these flags' - and I don't see  why it should work in dev but not prod. Clearly the default of false is not defined.